# JOOQ does not create insert statements in DAO

Tags: jooq

I have a table with two columns (both of type text) one of which is a primary key. Other is not null. I use jooq with following generate section:

```
<generate>
    <interfaces>true</interfaces>
    <daos>true</daos>
    <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
</generate>
```

The generated DAO does not contain insert methods. I don't see any warnings either. 
I am using `postgree DB`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to generate insert methods. The generated [`DAO`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DAO.html) classes extend [`DAOImpl`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DAOImpl.html), which already contains generic implementations, such as [`DAOImpl.insert(P)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DAOImpl.html#insert(P))

Comment: @Lukas, the insert methods doesn't return any value, how can I retrieve the ID auto generated by  the database then ?

Comment: @Cristiano: This question wasn't about returning IDs. jOOQ's `DAO` types don't have that feature (yet), you can use any other way of inserting data in jOOQ to fetch IDs.